# Tools for accurate modeling in blender?

Tags: blender

When using Sketchup I find 'Tape Measure' tool very useful for accurating modeling. I am wondering are there similar tools in blender?

Comment: And how exactly is this related to programming?

Comment: Better not reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1):

Dimension Lines For Blender With The Caliper Add-On.
The caliper script is a really nice add-on developed by an artist called macouno.
Check it here:
https://code.google.com/p/macouno/source/browse/trunk/Blender/addons/
Check for Caliper.py script

Hope it helps

3DPrinting Guys